# How to add the description of job in spring batch admin user interface?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Is there any way to add the description of job at the user interface of spring batch admin?

Although, I tried to added the description of the job, spring batch admin cannot support it.
I would like to know that whether spring batch admin does not support it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't the ability out of the box to display the job's description.  That is only contained in the XML and the data seen in the UI comes from the JobRepository.  You'd have to extend the UI to add that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I know i'm late to the party but I figured it out and it works flawlessly for me. All you have to do is :

1. Add a `messages.properties` file in your classpath (under
   src/main/resources).
2. Add `yourJobName.description=Your description goes here` in that file.
3. Override `manager-context.xml` for SBA by creating a file on path `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/override/manager-context.xml`
4. The content of the above created file should be :

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
  <!-- Override messageSource bean in order to provide custom text content -->
  <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

`

That's it. Your custom description shows up in SBA. Hope this helps someone who's looking for it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You just saved my day.